# How to remove the functions displayed by set command?

Tags: bash, shell, set

When set command is used without any options, it displays the names and values of all shell variables and functions.

We want to display only the variables and avoid the functions from the output.

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327848/getting-exporting-all-variable-names-in-zsh

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I already stated in a comment, `env` doesn't fit the requirement as it only shows exported variables.

Processing `set` output to filter out anything that doesn't look like a variable definition is an unreliable hack. You will in particular miss a part of variables which value contains a line feed. Even worst, a carefully written function can make appear fake variables definitions.

The simplest solution is to switch temporarily to the POSIX mode where functions are not considered to be (kind of) variables:

```
set -o posix
set
set +o posix
```

There is however an issue if your default mode is already POSIX, or if you want that command to work whatever POSIX mode the shell is set to.

In such case, here is a workaround:

```
(set -o posix;set)
```

This only set the POSIX mode for the `set` builtin executed in a subshell and the parent shell mode stay unaffected.

Comment: @jiliagre I guess even this would work `set | grep -E '^\S+=\S'`....right @terdon?

Comment: @FarhanPatel not for everything. See jlliagre's [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328394/how-to-remove-the-functions-displayed-by-set-command/328403#comment577914_328403) on my answer. This approach is better.

Comment: POSIX mode has the drawback of outputting multiline variables on multiple lines. While without POSIX mode, `set` outputs multiline variables as `foobar=$'foo\nbar\nbaz'` on a single line. Which is easier to parse then.

Answer (score 4):

While the simplest solution is to use `env` instead of `set`, `env` doesn't give *all* existing variables but only those that would be passed to any process started with `env` (so no unexported variables, for example). Another approach is to search the output of `set` for lines that have a string of non-whitespace, an `=` and then another string of non-whitespace characters:

```
set | grep -E '^\S+=\S'
```

However, this will miss any variables set to a multiline value (like `IFS` whose default value includes a `\n`).

Comment: @jlliagre indeed it is, there was a PEBKAC there. What can it miss though? Can you think of an example?

Comment: With the previous commands, you were missing by design all legitimate variables with names starting with an underscore. You are still missing a part of multiline content variables (e.g. IFS) so the output of your command is not parseable. Finally, you might display fake variables from function definitions.

Comment: Not to mention you run an external command while the shell is able to provide the already filtered output a more efficient way.

Comment: @jlliagre yes indeed. Very true for multiline vars, hadn't thought of that. But `set` doesn't print functions. At least not on my system. What kind of fake variables are you thinking of?

Comment: Bash `set` builtin print functions, that's the whole point of the OP question. Here is an example of such a fake variable: `f() { a="a[ENTER]fubar=/tmp/gotcha[ENTER]b"; }` . In fact, the same trick might also be used with multiline variables.

Comment: @jlliagre I had first thought you were absolutely correct, then I tested by defining a function, running `set` and grepping for it, and I failed to find it. Now I'm on a different system, tested again and did find it so I'm back to thinking you were absolutely correct in the first place. I'll go back to work tomorrow and try it again. I probably just did something stupid but in my defense, I did test!

Comment: You might have been missing to see function definitions in`set` output because you might have been running bash in POSIX mode, or running dash, ksh or whatever shell variant.

Comment: Actually this solution works better for me because without posix mode, bash outputs variable definitions in one line even for multiline variables.

Answer (score 3):

For some odd reason, `declare -p` seems to list only variables:

```
$ declare -p
declare -x ANT_HOME="/usr/share/apache-ant"
declare -- BASH="/usr/bin/bash"
declare -r BASHOPTS="checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:histappend:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath"
declare -ir BASHPID
declare -A BASH_ALIASES=()
declare -a BASH_ARGC=()
declare -a BASH_ARGV=()
declare -A BASH_CMDS=()
...
```

Of course, this has the disadvantage that it outputs `declare` commands that can recreate the variable with all its attributes. Depending on what you intend to do with the output, that might actually be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but the cow would consider something.

```
 _____
( env )
 -----
        o   ^__^
         o  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

---

In other words, just use `env` instead.

---

I guess she's just read jilliagre's comment.

```
 ________________________________
/ But it will only show exported \
\ variables!                     /
 --------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (!!)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
             !! ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: :))) is  this a RTFM cow?

Comment: `env` will only show exported variables.

Comment: @PetrMatousu I don't know her from that side. A word's been round she's getting into musing about _please do my homework_ questions here.

Comment: @tomas, m new to shell scripting, could u pls explain me how this trick would achieve the objective.

Comment: @FarhanPatel he means use `env` instead of `set`. It's a command that prints out environment variables.

Comment: @terdon, yes `env` prints only the global environment variables, however `set` without any options prints LOCAL and GLOBAL shell variables and functions.So both ain't same right?

Comment: @FarhanPatel yes, that's true. See my answer for a way that parses `set`.